# non-destructive atomic add?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

If I have an atomic variable like so:

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> a = 5;
```

I'd like to atomically check whether `(a + 4)` is less than another variable, without over-writing the original value of `a`:

```
if(a.something(4) < another_variable){
    //Do not want a to be incremented by 4 at this point
}
```

I did a quick test on atomic `fetch_and_add()` and `++` and they all seem to increase the value of variable `a` afterwards. Is there a way I can atomically increment to test, without the result being permanent?

Comment: `another_variable -= 4` ?

Comment: What needs to be atomic if there is no visible side-effect outside this thread? Atomic with respect to what?

Comment: What's wrong with just `a + 4 < v` ?

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to talk about atomicity of various non-destructive operations. You want an atomic load instruction. The question is, what exactly should be loaded atomically? Only a, or a and b separately, or a and b together as a unit? The latter case is tricky but it's not clear why it would be needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(a + 4 < another_variable) // ...
```

This is the best you can get with a single atomic. You are data-race free, as the reading of the atomic is safe against concurrent writes, and all subsequent operations happen on a *copy* of the original atomic value. A more verbose but functionally equivalent version would be:

```
int const copy_of_a = a.load();
if(copy_of_a + 4 < another_variable) // ...
```

This is also the best you can get in terms of synchronization. You may be worried about the fact that `a` may be changed on another thread to a value that will change the outcome of the `if`.

Assume there was a function that did the whole operation atomically:

```
 if(a.plus4IsLessThan(another_variable) // ...
```

Then whether a concurrent change of `a` arrives in time to change the outcome of the test is *still* not known. You did not gain any additional guarantees in terms of synchronization.

If this is a problem for your program, it indicates that you are in need of a more powerful synchronization mechanism. Probably a `std::mutex` would be a good start.

Comment: std::atomic<T>::operator T() is equivalent to std::atomic<T>::load(), so `if(a + 4 < another_variable)` uses an atomic load just like a.load().

Comment: @JayMiller Good point. I personally have a habit of writing the `load()`s so I can identify the atomics more quickly in my own code, but of course your version might be preferable for better readability.

Comment: It depends whether you're optimizing for "Achtung! Atomics!" or "hey, this is just a number, don't worry your pretty little head about the atomics right now" and that can vary from use to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
if (a + 4 < another_variable) { ...
```

Which should be identical to:

```
if (a.load() + 4 < another_variable) { ...
```

By definition (§29.6.5/16-17, here `A` "refers to one of the atomic types" and "`C` refers to its corresponding non-atomic type"):

```
A::operator C() const volatile noexcept;
A::operator C() const noexcept;
```

> *Effects*: `load()`
>
> *Returns*: The result of `load()`

Neither of which modify `a`.